# No shadows cast/shown in viewport Material View for Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shadows

Please have a look at this comparison. I wonder if I'm missing something or if **Blender** can't currently cast **shadows within Material View** in the viewport if I'm **using Cycles**. As you can see, on the right, shadows are cast on the side of the object that's not being hit by light. That's not happening with Cycles *(on the left).* This is using Material View. If I change to Render View, it shows them, so it is not a wrong setting *(I mean, it's just the startup setting, just changed the Sun into another kind of lamp).*

[image: Material Views for Cycles & Blender Render. Shadow differences.]

It's my first time getting into Cycles, but this is stopping me. And I have already searched everywhere for an answer and failed. I mean, I took the time to search well because I wouldn't think this could happen, but apparently nobody else in the web asked for this.

The point here is that I need to work using the Material View. It is faster for modeling and texturing. It's what I've always used within Blender Render. But that won't work with Cycles, and I don't want to use the Render View "live" because it is slow and the constant render destroys my CPU. Even if I switch to GPU the processes are high resource users and use a lot of RAM *(not with a cube btw, this is just a quick test)*. My whole pc would be constantly busy with this only program and I don't get why, if until now, using Blender Render, I was able to do tons of stuff at the time without making my pc suffer because of Cycles. My pc's specs are not the problem: 16GB Ram /i7 8cores 2.5GHz /Geforce GT 650 2GB. Everything works here, of course a constant render doesn't properly, but I see no point in having a constant render unless I need it for feedback.

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the current material on the cube while in cycles and putting a new one on? This just occurred to me but I remember having similar troubles because Blender Render materials aren't fully converted when switching to cycles, might have something to do with it.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. In the example of the cube, the one in blender render it's the default simple white material, and in the case of the Cycles render, it's kind of the same. I got into node editor added a material and the plain white material for blender cycles came to life. It's no different from let's say creating a new cube after having switched into Cycles, and then assigning a material from nodes. I just tested and it's the same. And the material assigned IS a cycles one because it turns a mess once you change back into Blender render :D

Comment: Ah, okay. Do you think you could upload the .BLEND so I can fiddle with it? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ This website makes it easy

Comment: Sure, will do right now. Anyways, you'll find a plain file. It's not like a file of mine is not working, before even starting to work with cycles I started to test stuff. In order to check on blender render just create a new file and put the viewport into Material view, and you will realize that blender render cast shadow and cycles doesn't. But cycles yes does it only in Render view (and final render too of course)

Comment: Josh, here is the link to the file. Thanks a lot for the time!

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2120" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2120/)

Comment: Hmm. I'm stumped on this one. Creating a new project, putting it into cycles, and then switching to material, also creates this problem. I think it might not possible to do.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. It seems Blender hasn't implemented this into Cycles. Do you know if this can be notified to the programmers in any way? Oh, and thanks for your time! Really!

Comment: no problem, I think this problem counts as a bug, which you can submit a report for here: https://www.blender.org/support/

Comment: Why do you need light-aware shading while working? Only when working with lighting or materials you need to use the render view, otherwise it doesn't really matter. Also you can make the modeling with internal and just render in cycles if this makes so big a difference to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender does not currently support Shading in the Material Viewport while in cycles. (I'm only reposting this as the answer so you can mark this post as resolved by clicking the green check mark)